# separar array laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array

Recibo datos de una vista de esta manera, hay alguna forma de separarlos y que quede como el ejemplo de abajo?

```
    array:6 [▼
          "id_producto" => array:1 [▼
            "insumo" => "7"
          ]
          "precio" => array:1 [▼
            "precio" => "4500"
          ]
          "cantidad" => array:1 [▼
            "cantidad" => "1"
          ]
          "total" => array:1 [▼
            "total" => "4500"
          ]
          "estado" => 1
          "id_control" => 58
        ]
```

resultado esperado ,

```
   array:6 [▼
          "id_producto" =>  "7"
          ]
          "precio" =>  "4500"
          ]
          "cantidad" =>  "1"
          ]
          "total" =>  "4500"
          ]
          "estado" => 1
          "id_control" => 58
        ]
```

esta es solo una parte del problema, lo acoté para que sea más corto, 
muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Así como lo tienes, la solución más simple sería:

```
<?php

$miarray=["id_producto" =>[
            "insumo" => "7"
          ],
          "precio" =>  [
            "precio" => "4500"
          ],
          "cantidad" => [
            "cantidad" => "1"
          ],
          "total" => [
            "total" => "4500"
          ],
          "estado" => 1,
          "id_control" => 58
        ];

$array_parseado = [];

foreach($miarray as $key => $value ) {
    $array_parseado[$key]=is_array($value) ? array_values($value)[0]:$value;    
}

var_dump($array_parseado);
```

Pero con eso estoy asumiendo que el array que quieres parsear tiene sus valores anidados a lo sumo a un nivel de profundidad, entre otras cosas.